# Should I mention the number of followers of my blog in my SOP for grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I maintain a technical blog (posts are in direct correspondence with my interested field of study) which has around 150000 followers. I have two questions:

(a) Do I mention the number of followers in my SOP/CV?

(b) Would mentioning the fact that I maintain this technical blog have any impact in admissions? (or do I even mention the blog in my CV/SOP?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

(a) There is not harm in mentioning it. Of course, how they interpret it is up to the department. In my cohort (social sciences), there was one student with a blog that he runs that generates quite some views. I am sure he included that (views) in his application.

(b) I would imagine it can only have a positive effect on your application.

Comment: I could imagine a negative effect, if the committee thought that work on the blog might interfere with graduate work. To have built up 150,000 followers suggest a fair volume of material.

Comment: I would concede that it may be field/topic dependent but at least in my field and the two institutions that I have been in: such public educational projects were definitely viewed positively.

Comment: I'll clarify - I didn't mean that it _should_ be considered a negative, just that it is conceivable that it could raise some questions. Somebody with 150,000 YouTube followers is likely putting up fresh content on a pretty regular and demanding schedule. Somebody else who has developed some really cool software tools, not so much...

Comment: But a technical blog with 150K followers is much more impressive than a cosmetology/dance/unboxing YouTube channel with 150K followers.

Comment: @JonCuster At least they have to do relevant work for their blog. They could well be windsurfing or skiing every weekend or competitively practicing some sport. All of this would take a lot of time. The blog is at least a relevant hobby.

Comment: @skymningen I'll second that. I think to an assessor, it would also demonstrate very clearly a passion for the subject and a self-starting attitude to getting projects off the ground.

Comment: @skymningen - anybody capable of focusing on one skill in life is capable of focusing on another. The skills of time management transfer. You might be surprised how many professionals (science or otherwise) participate in time intensive activities like sports or music at a high level, and have done them for their entire life. Don't diss what others do just because it isn't your cup of tea.

Comment: @JonCuster I did not diss anything others do. I rather tried to make the point to not diss someone on a relevant hobby as a negative because they have to spend time on it because many others (including myself) do have similarly time intensive hobbies that are just not relevant and thus not mentioned in the SOP. I wanted to offset the "negative effect" you imagined. Most people in the committee probably have hobbies. Compared to all the irrelevant things an applicant could be (and should be) doing, a relevant hobby sure is not seen as a negative by a committee of academics (with hobbies).

Comment: @skymningen - I'm sorry you thought I was trying to diss anyone - I did stress above that I didn't think that the blog _should_ be an issue, but did see how it _could_ be an issue. However, your dismissal of hobbies (like windsurfing) as not 'relevant' for those in academia is quite short sighted. For those that do them, they are often seen as necessary to being creative and productive in their field, regardless of how many 'followers' they may have. I will gladly take on a post-doc who played a collegiate sport as an undergrad - they clearly know how to manage their time.

Answer (score 0):

I would mention the blog, for sure, especially if it is relating to the Topic of studies. It lifts the CV more than pushes it down, as it shows that you are genuinely interested in the field as well as devoted to started projects (it is not easy to keep a blog!). Moreover, you could mention it as an experience in communication with the masses and depending on an Institution you are applying to, it might be a huge benefit, as professionals who can communicate their topic to the public are very much wanted.

To mention the number of followers is up to you but I believe if the person reading your profile will be interested in the blog he/she would ask you to tell more about it during the interview, if they do not ask/mention it, most likely it is not important for them. So keeping the numbers to yourself might be an advantage as it would not irritate not interested ones.

At the end all that matters is how you manage to show it as an advantage that would help you in the position you are applying for.

Good luck!